# Jquery - Ajax form submit to MySQL query

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to write a script that displays a form where the user enters a password, submit the form and checks that the password exists in a MySQL table.

The issue I am having is when the form is submitted the query runs and returns a "success" or a "fail" but the returned data is displayed on the page where the query is.

What I need it to do is perform the form submit, check the data and depending on "success" load another page, or a "fail" display a warning.

My Jquery:

```
<?php if($_GET['Error9'] == 1) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#login_form').show();
function do_login(){
  var pass=$("#password").val();
  if(pass!="") {
    $("#loading_spinner").css({"display":"block"});
    $.ajax  ({
      type:'post',
      url:'do_login.php',
      data:{
    do_login:"do_login",
    password:pass
      },
    success:function(response) {
      if(response=="success") {
    window.location.href="clear_faults_submit.php";
      } else {
    $("#loading_spinner").css({"display":"none"});
    alert("Wrong Details");
      }
    }
  });
 } else {
   alert("Please Fill All The Details");
 }
return false;
}

</script>
<?php } ?>
```

A part of the query:

```
if(isset($_POST['password']))
{
require_once('../../Connections/conn.php');

$pass=$_POST['password'];

mysql_select_db($database_iMaint, $iMaint);
$select_data = "SELECT * FROM AdminPIN WHERE  AdminPIN='$pass'";
$pass = mysql_query($select_data, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_pass = mysql_fetch_assoc($pass);

 if($row_pass['AdminPIN'] = $_POST['password']) 
 {

  echo "success";
 }
 else
 {
  echo "fail";
 }
exit();
}
```

The form:

```
<div id = "login_form">
<form method="post" action="do_login.php" onsubmit="return do_login();">
<input type="text" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter PIN">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="login" value="DO LOGIN" id="login_button">
</form>
</div>
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong.
Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: if($row_pass['AdminPIN'] = $_POST['password'])
= is to set == or === is to compare.

Comment: @aserwin  hi,  Thanks, Now I see.

Comment: @aserwin Hi well spotted. I have corrected that but still have the issue that when the form is submitted it runs the page with the query and displays the result on the query page. For whatever reason it does not continue to run the Jquery script and redirect if the query returns "success". Can you see why?

Comment: The PHP file: Try to replace $_POST with $_REQUEST, or insert a print_r($_REQUEST) to see what's submitted to server.

Comment: You should consider to use the [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php) extension, not mysql.

Comment: @Gjermund Dahl  hi using $_REQUEST I get "Array ( [password] => 1951 [login] => DO LOGIN [PHPSESSID] => c7bb16766dc5fef7bde777ad6faf7d2b [amember_nr] => 6687b2df4ed7480162a796064774f9bc ) success" which is what I would expect. I can't see why this is displayed og the PHP page as my JQuery script should send the query and return the result of "success" or "fail".

Comment: Try to change the `form` tag to this: `<form onsubmit="return do_login();">`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I have just finished for the day. I will pick this up again in the morning. Again, thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168512/discussion-between-gjermund-dahl-and-dcjones).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `form` tag setup posts the form twice. There is a conflict between `action="do_login.php"` and the `onsubmit="return do_login();"`

At least, omit `action` when you handle form submitting with JavaScript, but feel free to have a look at the setup below:

HTML:

```
<form id="login">
  <input type="text" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter PIN">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#login", function() {
  var pass = $("#password").val();
  if (pass != "") {
    //ajax call goes here
  } else {
    alert("Please Fill All The Details");
  }
  return false;
})
```